# C# Cryptography Generic Method for any Algorithm

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography

At the moment i have 3 different methods for md5, sha1 and sha512. Some small parts are different, like using statement. Is it possible to create a generic method for all of these? I'm a intermediate and some topics are quite new for me.
Below the code (simplified). Ignore the "ConvertHashToString" method.
Thank you!

```
   public string CheckMd5(string filename)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                return ConvertHashToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
            }
        }

    }

    public string CheckSha512(string filename)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            using (var sha = SHA512.Create())
            {
                return ConvertHashToString(sha.ComputeHash(stream));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit like this:

```
private string CheckHash(string filename, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        using (algorithm) 
        {
            return ConvertHashToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(stream));
        }
    }
}

public string CheckMd5(string filename) => CheckHash(filename, MD5.Create());

public string CheckSha512(string filename) => CheckHash(filename, SHA512.Create());
```

If you want a single method, you need some way of specifying the algorithm. You can also use `CryptoConfig.CreateFromName` to create a hash instance from a string. Something like this:

```
public string CheckHash(string filename, string algorithm)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        using (var algorithm = (HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(algorithm)) 
        {
            return ConvertHashToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(stream));
        }
    }
}
```

You probably want to validate that `CryptoConfig.CreateFromName` returned a `HashAlgorithm` before attempting to cast.

Finally, you can use generics, but this doesn't use the factory methods. The factory methods work better in the .NET Core scenario, but it doesn't sound like that's an issue for you since you are using WinForms.

```
public string Check<THash>(string filename) where THash:HashAlgorithm, new()
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        using (var algorithm = new THash()) 
        {
            return ConvertHashToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(stream));
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
CheckHash<SHA512Managed>(file);
```

Comment: Thank you! What's the name of this way? Anonymous method?

Comment: The first is just some new C# 6 syntax called [expression bodied members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx).

Comment: The first implementation is generally bad practice. Objects should be Disposed where they are created. In the sample, I'm passing in a perfectly valid `MD5` object to `CheckHash` but after calling `CheckHash` my `MD5` object has for some reason been disposed. What if I intended to use it again? Nothing about `CheckHash` would indicate such behavior.

Comment: @dman2306 That's why the method is `private`. It's not part of a public contract, so don't use your own methods in a way they don't work.

Comment: @vcsjones True, but it is still generally bad practice. A statement like "your own methods" implies one developer. I work on projects with many, many developers. Following best practices helps make developing easier. A `private` keyword doesn't mean you can (or should) do things that violate good programming practice and style. And note, I didn't say "never do this," I said it's "generally bad practice" - which it is.